# Android draw circle with Path

Tags: android, android-animation, bezier

I'm trying to animate drawing out a circle. In my custom view, I have

```
private final Paint mPaint = new Paint() {
    {
        setDither(true);
        setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        setColor(Color.BLUE);
        setStrokeWidth(30.0f);
        setAntiAlias(true);
    }
};
...
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw();
    if (mOval == null) {
        mOval = new RectF(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
    }
    if (mPath == null) {
        mPath = new Path();
    mPath.moveTo(0, getHeight() / 2);
    }

    float sweepAngle = Math.min((float) mElapsedTime / 1000 * 60 * 1, 1) * 360;
    if (sweepAngle == 0) {
        mPath.reset();
    } else if (mCurrentAngle != sweepAngle) {
    mPath.arcTo(mOval, mCurrentAngle, sweepAngle);
    }
    mCurrentAngle = sweepAngle;
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```

At intervals, I'm updating `mElapsedTime` and calling `invalidate()`. However, nothing is drawn on the screen. I've tried several variations, but to no avail. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there an easier way to do this? Given a percentage of a circle, I want to be able to make that much of the circle be what is drawn on the screen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two things here:

1. You have to call `canvas.drawOval(...)` before drawing the arc onto the oval. Otherwise it won't show up. This is why my method didn't work.
2. `Canvas` has a `drawArc` method that takes a start angle and a degrees to sweep out. See [`Canvas.drawArc(RectF, float, float, boolean, Paint)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc(android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint)). This is what I was looking for to draw circles.

**EDIT:** here's the relevant code from my `View` subclass:

```
private final Paint mArcPaint = new Paint() {
    {
        setDither(true);
        setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        setColor(Color.BLUE);
        setStrokeWidth(40.0f);
        setAntiAlias(true);
    }
};

private final Paint mOvalPaint = new Paint() {
    {
        setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    RectF mOval = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom); //This is the area you want to draw on
    float sweepAngle = 270; //Calculate how much of an angle you want to sweep out here
    canvas.drawOval(mOval, mOvalPaint); 
    canvas.drawArc(mOval, 269, sweepAngle, false, mArcPaint); //270 is vertical. I found that starting the arc from just slightly less than vertical makes it look better when the circle is almost complete.
}
```

Comment: How can I draw this in the center of the canvas?

Comment: @user2095470, Canvas supports `getHeight()` and `getWidth()`, so you should be able to calculate where to put `mOval` based on that.