# Animation a circle around an image view

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

Hi i want to draw a circle animation around an image view..can any one please help me out..

Thanks

[image]

Here is the picture...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know this is what you want to do, but there are several custom views to help your work.

1. [HoloCircularProgressBar](https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar)
2. [CircularImageView](https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView)

Otherwise, you should draw a circle around image. Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558673/android-draw-circle-with-path).

Comment: well i am trying to animate the white circle just like progress bar around the image..

Comment: you can draw a path of circle around imageview at onDraw with drawArc(). CircularImageView maybe draw a circle like that.